# Duplicate color printer as black and white printer

Tags: kubuntu, printing

Using KDE (Kubuntu) it was very easy to get my new network printer running (it just appeared).

But as that printer is a color printer and I want to print only black and white most of the time (to save the costs for the quite expensive color toners) I want to duplicate that entry with different settings (force greyscale) and make that the default printer.
=> Then I could easily switch to a color print when I want to, but won't forget to usually print B/W.

But how can I do that?
The system settings don't allow to copy a printer.

Should I just copy the relevant file in `/etc/cups/ppd/`?

---

Edit 12.01.2020:
Digging deeper it seems my problem is that I want to duplicate an "IPP Everywhere" printer. It shows up very easy and prints fine. But I see currently no way to duplicate it's entry as then the selection of the PPD will cause me to go a different route. Even choosing the "Generic/IPP Everywhere" will result in a file at `/etc/cups/ppd` that does **not** have an entry of `PCFileName: "ippeve.ppd"` but one of `PCFileName: "pwgrast.ppd"` instead.
So far I have found no way to make a perfect duplication of the automatically generated entry.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install the printer a second time, with the settings that you want. I have the same printer installed twice, each with a different name, one set as duplex, one set as single spaced. It makes it easier than to have to go into the preferences each time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Kubuntu. **This answer is for Ubuntu (Gnome)**

## Go to the printer setup page

In Ubuntu it is under Settings > Devices > Printers

[image]

As you can see I already have a printer installed. We are going to install the same physical printer again and set it up for black and white printing. To do that, click on the green <kbd>Add...</kbd> button on top right corner. It should automatically find the existing printer (keep the printer on).

[image]

Select the existing printer and click on the green <kbd>Add...</kbd> button on top right corner. Now you should have "two" printers installed. We will change the location to indicate which one is black and white.

[image]

Click on the settings cog next to the newly added printer and select printer details.

[image]

Now you can change the Printer name or the location to what you want.

[image]

Now go back to printer settings cog and select printing options:

[image]

And change from Color to Grayscale.

[image]

Now you have two printers one color and one black and white.

Hope this helps

Comment: Digging deeper it seems my problem is that I want to duplicate an "IPP Everywhere" printer. It shows up very easy and prints fine. But I see currently no way to duplicate it's entry as than the selection of the PPD will cause me to go a different route. Even choosing the "Generic/IPP Everywhere" will result in a file at `/etc/cups/ppd` that does **not** have an entry of `PCFileName: "ippeve.ppd"` but one of `PCFileName: "pwgrast.ppd"` instead. So far I have found no way to make a perfect duplication of the automatically generated entry.

Comment: @Chris unfortunately my printer is old and does not do "IPP Everywhere". So I can't try out your scenario.