# Can't default printer to black and white on 18.04

Tags: drivers, printing, colors

I finally moved up to 18 from 16 and I'm trying to print in black and white but the 'only' choice is color both in the printer details, in additional printer settings -> and in printer options the color mode radio button 'only' has color whereas with 16 it had black and white or color.

I also checked the http://localhost:631/ printers control and there the option is only for color also.

Am I missing something or did they forget to include default black and white printing?

The printer is an HP 3630.  I didn't add any software or drivers, after the reinstall it recognized the printer and allowed me to print.  Printer is connected via wifi.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You may also want to look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199656/duplicate-color-printer-as-black-and-white-printer/1202334#1202334)

Comment: When I try to print something, the "Print" dialog appears. On the "General" tab I can select the printer, the page range, number of copies, etc. However, if I click on the "Color" tab, I have an option for "Print Color as Gray" (with an On/Off drop-down). In your case, does the "Print" dialog that pops up when you attempt to print something ~not~ have the "Color" tab?

Comment: Thanks 68186.  I followed your link to the duplicate printer solution and installed the same printer again.  The 'new' printer shows "driverless" whereas the old shows that the drivers are installed (automatically downloaded?)  The new 'driverless' printer allows for black and white printing.  Problem solved.  Seems the diver didn't help but rather the opposite.  Problem seems solved.

Comment: How do I close out this question?  @ PJ - yes, the tab 'only' had color.  But when I re-installed the printer 'without' the drivers, it allows black and white printing also.  Since it is solved I think I'll just leave it like this without the drivers and without the HP extras.

Comment: I am glad that you were able to solve the problem. The best way to "close" the the question is to write your own answer by clicking the button below. Provide all the details of what you did (as you explained in the comment) and a link to the referred solution. Then after the required wait time click on the gray check mark next to your answer and turn it green. This will mark that answer as your accepted correct answer and help others in the future.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137815/how-to-install-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner)

Answer (score 2):

## Here are some steps to try:

### Install `hplip`

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt install hplip hplip-gui
```

This will install the two apps if they are note already installed.

### Run setup

Make sure the printer is connected and turned on. Type the following command in the terminal:

```
hp-setup
```

This will open the HP printer setup app. If it does not find your network printer, you may have to use manual discovery and enter the IP address of the printer.

After this, you may have two printer icons in the setup. Try the new one and see if it allows you to print in black and white.

### Remove the Extra Printer

If you end up with two printers you can remove the one you don't want from the System Setup > Printers. Or use the following command:

```
sudo hp-setup -i -r
```

It will offer you a list of printers to choose from if it detects two or more HP printer setups. If it detects only one printer it will delete that printer. Thanks to [PJ Singh](https://askubuntu.com/users/100356/pj-singh) for this tip.

Hope this helps

Comment: By the way, you can remove the duplicate printer using `sudo hp-setup -i -r` from the command-line. It will offer you a list of printers to chose from to remove.

Comment: @PJSingh Thanks! I have added this to the answer.